# How to implement objects modification trace

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, trace

With django admin, we have an history of who altered an object and when. I would like to add an "old value", "new value" to this to be able to roll back if needed.

Plus I would like every modification made to my objects (also outside of admin) to be recorded as well.

The final objective is to be able to trace every modification of every object in the models and be able to roll back if needed.

Do you know if such a module already exists.

If not what would be the good start point ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't personally tried it but it sounds like you should check out [django-reversion](http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/).

Comment: hey, that sounds nice, i'll have a deeper look

Comment: Well I just tested it on a mini test-project and it seems nice. We will see when I'll try to implement it on my main project but thanks a lot !